# How to get compileSdkVersion in my custom gradle plugin

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I am writing a custom gradle plugin.
In my custom plugin, how can I get the compileSdkVersion of the host project.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve it from `project.android.compileSdkVersion`

```
apply plugin: CompileSdkVersionPlugin
...

class CompileSdkVersionPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.task('compileSdkVersion') {
            doLast {
                println project.android.compileSdkVersion
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then `gradle -q compileSdkVersion` command in the terminal will print this output:

```
android-25
```

Comment: I can't get 'android' field in 'project' instance, is it caused by my gradle version?

Comment: My gradle version is `3.4`, android gradle plugin version `2.3.0`

Answer (score 0):

In Addition, we can get the compilesdkversion even the android.jar path. In java code

```
private static String getAndroidJarPath(Project project) {
    AppExtension appExtension = (AppExtension)project.getProperties().get("android");
    String sdkDirectory = appExtension.getSdkDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    String compileSdkVersion = appExtension.getCompileSdkVersion();
    sdkDirectory = sdkDirectory + File.separator + "platforms" + File.separator
    String androidJarPath = sdkDirectory + compileSdkVersion + File.separator + "android.jar";
    return androidJarPath;
}
```