# Print the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion runtime of android app

Tags: android

I'm having a cordova outsystems android app and I want to make sure it's running the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion that I've set. Is it possible to print it out runtime in android code (not javascript)?

Comment: You can get [the `targetSdkVersion`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo#targetSdkVersion) through `PackageManager`, though you can only get [the `compileSdkVersion`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo#compileSdkVersion) on Android 12 and higher.

Comment: PackageManager exposes the getTargetSdkVersion method but I don't see a getCompileSdkVersion.

Comment: You would need to set your `compileSdkVersion` to 31. I linked to [the documentation for the `compileSdkVersion` field on `ApplicationInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo#compileSdkVersion).

Answer (score 1):

Getting the targetSdkVersion is simple:

```
  val targetSdkVersion = application.applicationInfo.targetSdkVersion
```

Getting the compileSdkVersion is more complex, there are answers posted here:
[How to get compileSdkVersion in my custom gradle plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43026263/how-to-get-compilesdkversion-in-my-custom-gradle-plugin)

Comment: targetSdkVersion  works, thanks! I tried the answers for the compileSdkVersion but doesn't work.